# How to do auto-width with HTML IFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to use iframe to open other URLs. But for reason the width iframe is fixed in 155px.

I need to resize the width iframe to fit the whole SRC iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.gnu.org/"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried width="100%", but didn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3LAat/5/)**</kbd>

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
.h_iframe iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.h_iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="h_iframe">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9KunP3sZyI0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: EXCELLENT SOLUTION!

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
    <iframe 
        src="http://www.gnu.org/" 
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no" 
        style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" 
        height="100%" 
     width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: can you explain why your solution solves the problem?

Comment: Didn't work. But Gaurav's response worked fine. I think it was missing the CSS to HTML and Body.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this with CSS

for example.

```
style="width:100%"
```

I just pasted your HTML into a fiddle. And it works as intended.
Do you have any css overruling the width, or is it inside a container which is 155px wide where you actually use it?

That works for me at least.

Comment: No CSS. And I also tried on jsfiddle and I got the same result.

Answer (score -1):

this works without css:

```
<iframe src="link-goes-here" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Everything in style="..." is still CSS, you're just inlining it inside the HTML instead of placing it by itself in an external stylesheet.